# convert a nested list into dataframes based on row index

Tags: python, list, dataframe, nested

I got a nested list with of the shape `[<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe9da238b80>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7fe9d7469b50>, 0.029849157929994773]` with a total of 7332920 entries.
I converted this list into a DataFrame and adding column names using:

`distances = pd.DataFrame(results)`

`distances.columns = ['point', 'polygon', 'distance']`

| point | polygon | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POINT (6.923344699999999 50.9169508) | POLYGON Z ((6.9571231 50.9285122 0, 6.957724 5... | 0.223 |

now i want to split it into 40 data frames of size 183323 each.
I tried:

`lst_distances = [distances.iloc[i:i+183323] for i in range(0,len(distances), 183323)]`

But now i don't know how to convert this nested list into 40 different lists or dataframes **without** going through each manually like this:
`d1, d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18,d19, d20, d21,d22,d23, d24,d25,d26,d27,.... = map(list, zip(*lst_distances)`

I can't go directly from the dataframe because the polygon item is not hashable.

Comment: The question is not clear: It seems that you already splitted  `distances`  in the 40 dataframes elements of  `lst_distances`.

Comment: i split it into a nested list ```list_distances``` but now i want to split this into different data frames

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with the list?
You already have `lst_distances[0]`, `lst_distances[1]`,

Using a dictionary is another way but it does not bring any avantage.

```
d = {str(i+1):e for (i,e) in enumerate(lst_distances)}
```

defines d['1'], d['2'], ...

Now, if you **really** want variables:

1. "manual" solution*

   ```
   d1, d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18,d19,d20,_
   d21,d22,d23, d24,d25,d26,d27,.... = tuple(lst_distances)
   ```
2. Acceding the globals

   ```
   for (i,dist) in enumerate(lst_distances):
       globals()[f"d{i+1}"] = dist
   ```

   Should not be used for `locals()` [by the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) but would work on most implementations.
3. Introducing dynamic code with using `exec`

   ```
   exec("\n".join([f"d{i+1} = lst_distances[i]" for i in range(len(lst_distances))]))
   ```